Why is typescript declaring my parameter as undefined?
In the following function I am trying to call the ProductServices's getSelectProduct method.
  private getSelectedProduct = () => {
    const productId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('productId');
    console.log('selectedProduct', productId)
    this.productService.getSelectedProduct(productId).subscribe(product => {
      this.selectedProduct = product;
    })
  }

Typescript is giving me a red squiggly under the productId in this statement: getSelectedProduct(productId). The error message is:

Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
const productId: string | null

This is the declaration of selectedProduct: public selectedProduct?:ProductModel;
This is the getSelectedProduct method:
public getSelectedProduct = (productId:string) => {
    const product = this.productSignal().products.find(product => product._id === productId)
    return of(product)
  }


productId can be either string or null. getSelectedProduct only accepts string. You'll have to handle the case when productId is null.

The error message is clear: The variable can be null, but the function don't accept it, so it errors out. Check why the early get method returns null and if it's correct, handle that case before the getSelectedProduct call.

Based on Guy Incognito advice: account for case when productId is null;
private getSelectedProduct = () => {
    const productId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('productId');
    console.log('selectedProduct', productId)
    if(productId !== null) {
      this.productService.getSelectedProduct(productId).subscribe(product => {
        this.selectedProduct = product;
        console.log('selectedProduct', this.selectedProduct)
      })
    }    
}

